# I set value of an input tag with javascript and when submit the form, the value is undefined in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have write a script to set value of an input tag with javascript and I receive error Notice: Undefined index in php. The value of input tag change correctly but when I submit form, value is undefined.

here are form in **HTML Javascript**

```
<form method="post" action="validate.php">
    <div>
        <label for="Deadline">Deadline</label>
        <select name="Deadline" id="Deadline" onchange="getOption()">
            <option value="none">Choose Account Deadline</option>
            <option value="31">1 Month</option>
            <option value="62">2 Month</option>
            <option value="93">3 Month</option>
            <option value="124">6 Month</option>
            <option value="366">1 Year</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" disabled>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Check To Buy</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getOption() {
        let jprice = 0;
        const e = document.getElementById("Deadline");
        const p = document.getElementById("price");
        const output = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if (output === "none") {
            p.setAttribute('value', '');
        }

        else {
            if (output === "31") {
                jprice = 159000;
            }
            else if (output === "62") {
                jprice = 300000;
            }
            else if (output === "93") {
                jprice = 450000;
            }
            else if (output === "124") {
                jprice = 600000;
            }
            else if (output === "366") {
                jprice = 1000000;
            }
            p.setAttribute('value', jprice.toString());
        }
    }
</script>
```

here is **PHP Code - validate.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $act = $_POST['accounttype'];
    $Deadline = $_POST['Deadline'];

    $price = $_POST['price']; //error is here

    echo "Account Type: " . $act . "<br>\n";
    echo "Deadline: " . $Deadline . "<br>\n";
    echo "Price: ";
    echo $price;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `e.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html no input call accounttype so its value is undefined
and html not passing disabled input value to php so it also undefined you can fix it using readonly

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // $act = $_POST['accounttype'];
    $Deadline = $_POST['Deadline'];

    $price = $_POST['price']; 

    echo "Account Type: " . $act . "<br>\n";
    echo "Deadline: " . $Deadline . "<br>\n";
    echo "Price: ";
    echo $price;
} 



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <div>
        <label for="Deadline">Deadline</label>
        <select name="Deadline" id="Deadline" onchange="getOption()">
            <option value="none">Choose Account Deadline</option>
            <option value="31">1 Month</option>
            <option value="62">2 Month</option>
            <option value="93">3 Month</option>
            <option value="124">6 Month</option>
            <option value="366">1 Year</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" readonly="true">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Check To Buy</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getOption() {
        let jprice = 0;
        let e = document.getElementById("Deadline");
        let p = document.getElementById("price");
        let output = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(output)

        if (output == "none") {
            p.value='';
        }
        else {
            if (output === "31") {
                jprice = "159000";
            }
            else if (output === "62") {
                jprice = "300000";
            }
            else if (output === "93") {
                jprice = "450000";
            }
            else if (output === "124") {
                jprice = "600000";
            }
            else if (output === "366") {
                jprice = "1000000";
            }
            p.value=jprice;
         }
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you dear Ess for your helping

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing the `disabled` attribute from this line

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" disabled>
```

then try again, I hope this fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks you dear Ess for your helping

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setAttribute` to change an input's value, assign to the `value` property.

```
p.value = jprice;
```

Comment: Thanks you dear Barmar for your helping